# 3 different devices with Ubuntu 14.05 & 15.04 can't connect WIFI (Huawei HG552E)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, 15.04

Android (my phone and tablet) and Windows 8 (desktop, netbook, laptop) devices are able to connect my WIFI.

When I boot my laptop with Windows 8, it's able to connect my WIFI.

When I boot same laptop with Ubuntu it's trying to connect sometime and says like: "Disconnected from Wifi"
Also with Ubuntu my laptop can connect other WIFI modems.

**I think there is problem with Ubuntu and my modem Huawei HG552E.**

1- I've changed almost every mode of WIFI setting in modem interface. 
2- Also tried to disable password protection for WIFI.
3- With fresh installation with 15.04 also does not working.
4- I'm able to connect internet with wired cable.

I'm not able to connect WIFI with 3 different Ubuntu please help :(
http://prntscr.com/73c2a1

Comment: http://prntscr.com/73c45k

Comment: Same problem. I have been trying to solve it for days...

Comment: Hi brother, here is a firmware update: https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=46859.msg542570#msg542570 The post is Turkish but it simply says that download the firmware and install the main.bin file to the modem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a firmware problem in HG552e modems. I was trying to solve this problem for 9-10 days. A few minutes ago, I saw that post in [ubuntu-tr forums](https://forum.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?topic=46859.msg542570#msg542570).

The man says the following:

- first [download](https://yadi.sk/d/T5LgZQYIg5jyE) this package.
- Extract the package. Open your modem interface.
- Install `HG552eV100R001C192B013_upgrade_main.bin` file as software
  update via modem interface.

This steps solved my problem.